Phase diagram of ammonium hydrosulfide, a volatile salt
Salts (ionic compounds) usually have low volatility due to the strong ionic bond.
However, there are exceptions. Smelling salts decompose and release ammonia gas.
What is "volatile"?
If a chemical decomposes into gases when heated, is it volatile? Sugars decompose into steam and carbon. But when you cool it back down it does not re-form into sugar.
Ammonium hydrosulfide also decomposes into its constitute gases:
$\ce{NH4^+HS- <-> NH3 + H2S}$
But, crucially, the original salt is reformed upon condensation via the reverse reaction. This makes it behave like a phase-change. For example, equilibrium vapour pressure curves are well-defined and the salt can be distilled. Cloud decks of this putrid compound condense around the -70C layer on Jupiter and Saturn. Much like Earth's water cycle.
For the purposes of this question, "evaporation" can either refer to a purely physical process or a reversible decomposition reaction.
Molecular or ionic?
It is unclear to me if ammonium hydrosulfide crystals are ionic as is table salt or if they are made up of individual neutral molecules (as does an N-oxide zwitterion). The latter isn't really a "salt" because there is no ionic lattice in the solid phase.
Physical property questions
Are ammonium hydrosulfide crystals truly ionic, the way NaCl is? If it can be melted, does the liquid conduct electricity?
Is this salt the most volatile ionic compound known?
Does the substance even have a triple point? Following the sublimation line from 57C and 1atm upward, there may never be a separate liquid phase. If it decomposes much more easily than it melts, by the time it is hot enough to melt the equilibrium pressure of the decomposition gases could be so high that it is just a supercritical soup with no distinct liquid and gas phases.

Being volatile means that molecules (or ionic pairs) of a substance easily leave its condensed phase to the gaseous phase, Reversible decomposition is still decomposition.

@Poutnik: Yes there isn't a good term for "the compound can be evaporated and then re-condensed, but said evaporation is actually a reversible decomposition instead of a simple phase change." It still makes sense to construct "phase diagrams" of density and enthalpy as a function of temperature and pressure. What does such a phase diagram look like?

It would not be a phase diagram, but a p-T diagram of the prevalent substances (may have a dedicated name, I cannot remember), similarly as there is Pourbaix_diagram for Potential-pH for various oxidation states and forms of elements and substances.

Considering your idea seriously, one could take e.g. the gaseous mixture  N2  + H2O + O2 in molar ratio 1 : 4 : 1 as the gaseous phase of NH4NO3(s), that is kinetically stable and does not undergo condensation back to the solid.

Yes my term "phase diagram" is a bit inaccurate. You could think of NH4NO3 as a metastable form of H2O+N2+O2 and plot on the P-T diagram where it is kinetically stable. In my example, NH4HS is thermodynamically stable at high P and low T and I am only considering what is thermodynamically stable at each PT value.
